# How to let an Android service stop itself when finished?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm implementing a service in my application. I want to stop the service by itself when the uploading task is finished. I'm trying to detect the network and when wifi or mobile network is available then start to upload my data on server and after finishing the uploading task to stop the service itself in the `onCreate()` method. I log a message when the service starts, but i don't understand why even after the call `this.stopSelf()` it continuously prints the message of stop service. How to use services properly in Android?

Here is my Service code.

```
public class ServiceTest extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 2000, 15 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private Timer mTimer;

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            getConnectivityStatusString(getApplicationContext());
        }
    };

    public String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = Constant.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        String status = null;
        if (conn == Constant.TYPE_WIFI)
        {
            status = "Wifi enabled";
            Log.e("", " status = " + status);

            ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            {
                NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (netInfo == null)
                {
                    Log.e(" Not "," Accessible !!!");
                }
                else
                {

                    Log.e(" Start ", " To Loading !!!!");
                    //new Welcome_Page().execute();
                    this.stopSelf();
                    Log.e(" Stop ", " The Service !!!!");
                }
            }

        } else if (conn == Constant.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = "Mobile data enabled";
            Log.e(""," status = "+status);
            this.stopSelf();
            Log.e(" Stop ", " The Service !!!!");
        } else if (conn == Constant.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = "Not connected to Internet";
            Log.e(""," status = "+status);
        }
        return status;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            mTimer.cancel();
            timerTask.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.techtrainner");
        intent.putExtra("yourvalue", "torestore");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver class code.

```
public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceTest.class));
    }
}
```

Here is my network code.

```
public class Constant
{
    public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)

                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        }
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
}
```

Comment: stopService(new Intent(YOUR_CONTEXT.this, ServiceTest.class)) ....Use these and let me know in case of concern

Comment: @Ravindra Kushwaha : Can i put this line in ServiceTest.class  -
stopService(new Intent(YOUR_CONTEXT.this, ServiceTest.class))

Comment: No need to put it inside the Service class...You just put these line of code where , your operation is completed

Comment: I want stop itself even my app is not in run mode or app is already exit or not open mode.

Comment: @Ravindra Kushwaha : I'm trying to upload queue in service which is run in the background when internet connection is available.Please tell me where i have to put your suggested code line(stopService(new Intent(YOUR_CONTEXT.this, ServiceTest.class)) )

Comment: I have only 1 reputation so can't move this discussion to chat. Sorry

Comment: Yeah , i tried .But i want to stop automatically.

Comment: use stopSelf(); Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485298/stopself-vs-stopselfint-vs-stopserviceintent

Answer (score 2):

Try these in the manifest like these

```
<service
    android:name=".ServiceTest"
    android:stopWithTask="true" />
```

And for the progrmatically , stop the service:-

```
stopService(new Intent(YOUR_CONTEXT.this, ServiceTest.class))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return this **START_NOT_STICKY** on this **onStartCommand** method

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

after you can write  **stopSelf();** method for stop service whenever you want.
Add your service in menifest file like this

```
<service
        android:name=".YourService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

Comment: Still service is started and print the message .

Comment: one more thing try to remove onCreate() method and call your timer on  onStartCommand method

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Service to stop itself after performing some particular task

It's better to Use IntentService instead of Service class

You can find more on it here

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Look for IntentService section