# how to find what destroyed the service

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

Is it possible to identify who destroyed the service ?

I have a service that is running in the background and when the user clicks a button i call

```
 stopService(myService):
```

and

```
onDestroy()
```

is then called . Sometimes the service is destroyed by the operating system for one reason or another . is it possible to find out if the user stopped it or was it the system ?

I have a service that read accelerometer data and based on it an action is taking .

the service i running fine but some times the system terminates this service and when that happens i want to service to restart self using AlarmManager after a set seconds of time.

I want to check in onDestroy() if the user is the one who stopped the service thats by callking stopService() or the system did . if the user did then there is no need to restart the service but if it was the system then restart it

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22711201/5110595)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to be sure but you're most likely looking at the background limitations of Android Oreo. To increase battery life all background services will be stopped by the system a few minutes after the app moves to the background.

More information about the background limitations can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).

If your Android version is lower than Oreo or your app is still in the foreground you'll need to provide more information about the circumstances.

Comment: I don't know if you'll be able to tell who or what shut your service down. However I can tell you that what you're trying to do will never work on Android Oreo and higher because of the background limitations. You really need to educate yourself about how Oreo changed background services, a lot has changed and you won't be able to just apply a quick fix or dirty trick.

Answer (score 0):

stopService() & stopSelf() are called only when you want to explicitly destroy service which in turn call onDestroy().

And onDestroy() will also be called when you service finishes itself.

Please refer for more details:

[Android: stopService() doesn't call onDestroy()!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086371/android-stopservice-doesnt-call-ondestroy)

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Answer (score 0):

@HemantParmar gave a good link to read, it is simple to check if user destroyed the service or system itself, whenever you call `stopService()` use a boolean flag.

```
//runningService.stopit();
// OR
stopService(RunningService); // user called

boolean iStopped = true;


public void stopit(){
   //stopSelf();
}

public void onDestroy(){
  super.onDestroy();
  if(iStopped){
   // user did it
  }else{
   // system did it
  }
  iStopped = false; // whoever did it , reset it
}
```

Comment: and how do i call stopit() method in the service ?

Comment: if inside the service just call `stopIt()` if outside the service , use service instance and call like `runningService.stopit()`